# Custom changes in Sonata Admin PreUpdate prevent persiting of object

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata

I am using Doctrine 2.4.8 in my Symfony 2.8.34 project.

My Problem is that custom changes I made in the `preUpdate` function preventing the expected changes from the admin form. Dependent on a choice field a new event should been created or deleted.

```
class CustomAdmin extends AbstractAdmin {

   public function preUpdate($object) {
      ...
      if ($object->isDetached()) {
         $event = new Event();
         ...
         $object->setDetachedEvent($event);
      } else {
         $object->setDetachedEvent(null);
      }
   }
}
```

Now, the line `$object->setDetachedEvent(null);` turns everything crazy. The first time I'm saving the form my custom changes in that `preUpdate` function are executed, but the changes in the fields of the admin form are ignored. The second time the changes from the admin form were executed. If I remove the line above, everythings works fine.

So, anybody has an idea how to handle this problem?